# Create table if it does not exist, and enter one row after creating

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to create a table if it does not exist, and when it is created add a single row to it.

I'm new to oracle and PL/SQL so I basically need an equivalent of the following T-SQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('my_table', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE my_table(id numeric(38,0), date datetime)    
  INSERT INTO my_table
  VALUES (NULL, 0)
END
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this requirement? Is it a homework question? Typically, you should not be creating tables in PL/SQL - tables are permanent objects that should be created once and then used in any code. If you're after a table to house data temporarily, then consider creating a Global Temporary Table (GTT), which is a permanent table that allows data to be stored temporarily on a per-session basis (ie. session 2 can't see data in the GTT that session 1 stored and vice versa).

Comment: its like you are using sybase syntax

Answer (score 4):

if you want to check table creation

```
DECLARE count NUMBER;
BEGIN
count := 0;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO count from user_tables WHERE table_name= 'MY_TABLE';
IF COL_COUNT = 0 THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table ....';
END IF;
END;
/
```

A checking for `DML` .please note you have to sepcify your pk columns and values.

```
DECLARE count NUMBER;
BEGIN
count := 0;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO count from MY_TABLE WHERE id= 0 and name='Something';
IF COL_COUNT = 0 THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into MY_TABLE (id,name) values(0,''something'') ';
END IF;
END;
/
```

also note I recomand to specify columns when you insert into a table

Comment: Maybe also worth showing that the insert has to be done dynamically too? (And setting `col_count` - which you have inconsistent names for! - to zero is redundant.)

Comment: @AlexPoole okay ill add a checking  for the insert

Comment: I meant in the same block, straight after the dynamic create. Doesn't quite make sense in a separate block; if the select works (because the table now exists) then the insert doesn't need to be dynamic. But the OP seemed to want to do create/insert as one step; so you would have the two `execute immediate` statements together in the first block?

Comment: @AlexPoole well I meant to provide a better way ? anyway ill include it ine one block

Comment: The better way is to have a permanent table and not have to do this at all *8-)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use exception logic. I changed field names and types according to Oracle rules

```
declare
  eAlreadyExists exception;
  pragma exception_init(eAlreadyExists, -00955);
begin
  execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE my_table(id number, dateof date)';
  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (NULL, sysdate)';
  exception when eAlreadyExists then 
      null;  
end;
```

but may be it is not a good idea to create tables dynamically

Comment: *but may be it is not a good idea to create tables dynamically* I agree but just curious, what is your explanation why not to create tables dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should not be creating objects on the fly. You should think about your design before implementing it.

Anyway, if you really want to do it this way, then you need to do it programmatically in **PL/SQL** (ab)using **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**.

However, I would prefer the **CTAS** i.e. `create table as select` if you want to create a table ta once with a single row. For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT 1 id, SYSDATE dt FROM DUAL;

Table created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

        ID DT
---------- ---------
         1 29-MAY-15

SQL>
```

The table is created permanently.

If you are looking for a temporary table, which you could use to store **session specific data** , then look at [**creating Global temporary table**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633).

From documentation,

> Use the CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE statement to create a temporary
>   table. The ON COMMIT clause indicates if the data in the table is
>   transaction-specific (the default) or session-specific

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NOT EXISTS](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exists.php) with select statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM my_table) THEN
CREATE TABLE my_table(id NUMBER, date date);
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO my_table(id, date) values (NULL, O);
COMMIT;
END IF;
```

**UPDATE**

According to the comment, I cannot use Exist directly in PL/SQL. So this is another way to do it:

```
begin
  select case
           when exists(select 1
                         from my_table)
           then 1
           else 0
        end into l_exists
   from dual;

  if (l_exists = 1)
  then
    -- anything
  else
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE my_table(id NUMBER, date date)';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO my_table(id, date) values (NULL, O)';
  end if;
 end;
```

Comment: No you can't; you can't use `IF` in plain SQL anyway, but if you could the `SELECT 1 FROM my_table` would still get ORA-00942. If you did this in a PL/SQL block you'd have to do the create and insert dynamically, and you can't use `exists` directly in PL/SQL either, only in SQL.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks. I've suggested another way to do it.

Comment: Hmm. Did you try your solutions? :) As @AlexPoole said your script will not compile, because MY_TABLE does not exists. The IF section either not compile but by different reason, you forgot declaring etc.. You need to check the existance of the table via selecting from user_tables, all_objects or something like that. So the NOT EXISTS is for queries, not for testing objects existance.